# Filtering on dates with grep and awk

Tags: shell-script, grep, awk

I have created the alias below in my `.bash_aliases` file

```
alias auth="grep \"$(date|awk '{print $2,$3}')\" /var/log/auth.log |
            grep -E '(BREAK-IN|Invalid user|Failed|refused|su|Illegal)'"
```

This is supposed to:

- check todays date
- grep `auth.log` for todays messages
- grep todays messages for warning messages matching particular strings

However, it only works when there's a 2-digit day because days numbered <10 do not have a preceding zero.

For example, I run `date` and pipe the result to `awk`. `date` outputs `Sat Jan  1 04:56:10 GMT 2011` and then awk captures `$2` and `$3` and feeds them into grep as follows

```
Jan 1
```

However, when there's a single digit day, messages in `auth.log` appear as follows

```
Jan  1 00:44:57 linux su[21249]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
```

So there are two spaces following `Jan` in the `auth.log` but only one space following `Jan` in my grep command

How can I modify the command to allow for the additional space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than using `date | awk ...`, you can use a format specifier with the date command for the format you want. According to the `date(1)` man page, `%b` is the abbreviated month name, and `%e` is the day of month, space padded, same as `%_d`.

The following date command should give you a string in the form you want:

```
date "+%b %e"
```

You can also put other characters into the format specifier, so if you use:

```
date "+^%b %e"
```

you'll get a grep pattern that matches the date only at the beginning of the line. This would prevent any false matches where there is a date in the message part of the log.

As pointed out by Steven D, you can also do this with a single invocation of `grep`:

```
auth()
{
    grep -E "$(date '+^%b %e')"'.*(BREAK-IN|Invalid|user|Failed|refused|su|Illegal)' /var/log/auth.log
}
```

I've made a few changes based on issues mentioned in comments related to quoting. My rules for quoting are to use single quotes when grouping separate words into a single word and to protect against shell expansion of metacharacters, and to use double quotes only when you want to expansion inside a multi-word string.

The original answer had the `date` format string in double quotes, which was wrong according to my above rules. I've now changed that. An edit put the grep string into double quotes. I've put it back into single quotes because there is so often an overlap between shell metacharacters and grep regular expression (RE) metacharacters that you almost always want to single-quote REs to grep. The current string may not need single quotes but if this shell function evolves over time, it may break with future changes.

Because the question was asking about a command to put inside an alias, there was an additional level of quoting that was not shown in this answer. It would be simpler to use a shell function instead of an alias so you don't need to deal with this extra level of quoting. Nested quoting can get messy quickly, so anything you can do to avoid it, you should do.

I have tested this as a shell function, using Gilles suggestion for futzing the date and it "works for me".

Comment: You can also reduce the calls to `grep` to 1.

Comment: @Steven D: that's right. I'm in the process of testing an edit that does that. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: This isn't actually working, I'll play around with it.  The first section works but the piece contained in the single-quotes doesn't, even if I replace 'BREAK-IN...Illegal' with 'Jan'

Comment: This works `grep -E "$(date "+^%b %e")".*"(BREAK-IN|Invalid user|Failed|refused|su|Illegal)" /var/log/auth.log`

Comment: @Griffo: The `.*` should definitely be quoted. What system and shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu and bash.  I just ran the command with the date of Jan 1st and Jan 15th.  This command works from command line `grep -E "$(date '+^%b %e')".*'(BREAK-IN|Invalid user|Failed|refused|su|Illegal)' /var/log/auth.log` and this works as an alias `alias auth="grep -E \"$(date '+^%b %e')\".*'(BREAK-IN|Invalid user|Failed|refused|su|Illegal)' /var/log/auth.log"`

Comment: I've edited the post a bit to fix the quoting.  The version I've posted works for me.

Comment: @Steven D: The change in quoting was unnecessary and makes it worse (changes single quotes to double quotes). I assume that @Griffo's problems were because of the extra quotes added to make the command an alias. I would use a shell function instead and keep the same quoting. And the argument to `date` should be single quoted. That was my mistake.

Comment: @camh: Under Linux, you can use `date -d '10 days ago' '+^%b %e'` to test.